# Equivalence of 'vlookup' in R for multiple columns?

Tags: r, vlookup

I have a 9801 by 3 reference table.
The first 2 columns of this table is defined as follows.

```
x1 = x2 = seq(0.01,0.99,0.01)
x12 = data.matrix(expand.grid(x1,x2))
```

The 3rd columns contains the outcome values.

Now I have another n by 3 matrix where the 1st and 2nd columns are selected rows of the above matrix 'x12' and the 3rd column is to be filled. I would like fill in the 3rd column of the 2nd table by looking up the same combination of the 1st and 2nd column in the 1st table and find the value in the 3rd column.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the `merge` function:

```
# Original data frame
x1 = x2 = seq(0.01,0.99,0.01)
x12 = expand.grid(x1,x2)

# Add a fake "outcome"
x12$outcome = rnorm(nrow(x12))

# New data frame with 100 random rows and the first two columns of x12
x12new = x12[sample(1:nrow(x12), 100), c(1,2)]

# Merge the outcome values from x12 into x12new
x12new = merge(x12new, x12, by=c("Var1","Var2"), all.x=TRUE)
```

`by` tells `merge` which columns must match when comparing the two data frames. `all.x=TRUE` tells `merge` to keep all rows from the first data frame, `x12new` in this case, even if they don't have a match in the second data frame (not an issue here, but you'll often want to make sure you don't lose any rows when merging).

One other thing to note is that, unlike vlookup in Excel, `merge` will increase the number of rows in the new, merged data frame if there are multiple rows that match the criteria. For example, see what happens when you merge values from `df2` into `df1`:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), z=c(10,20,30,40))
df2 = data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,3), y=c("a","b","c","a","c"))
merge(df1, df2, by="x", all.x=TRUE)
```

> ```
>   x  z    y
> 1 1 10    a
> 2 1 10    b
> 3 1 10    c
> 4 2 20    a
> 5 3 30    c
> 6 4 40 <NA>
> ```

You can also use `left_join` from the `dplyr` package (other types of joins are available as well):

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by="x")
```